# Dailymotion videos not showing on Chrome 18. How to fix it?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

When I started to install Google Chrome, I noticed a problem on Dailymotion:

[image]

As you can see in the link of the image above, it doesn't seem to show the video.

Is there any solution to fix this?
Version of Ubuntu: 12.04
Version of Google Chrome: 18.0.1025.142

Answer (score 0):

Please try temporarily disabling your adblocker and reloading the page (click on the red "stop sign with a hand" in the upper-right of your screen, choose disable, then refresh). Let us know if that helps. or if it doesn't fix the problem.

--Nick

Comment: Unfornately, it doesn't show disable because it's from an older version, 2.5.34, so how do I find that option?

Comment: Does clicking on it disable it or bring up a menu? What about right-clicking on it?

Comment: Tried it! :( It didn't work neither. It still doesn't show the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the cache web browser :

Delete all your browsing data

1. Open Chrome.
2. In the top right, click the Menu Chrome Menu.
3. Click More tools > Clear browsing data.
4. In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
5. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data you want to delete.
6. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
7. Click Clear browsing data.

Comment: I didn't work. :( I cleaned the cache as you said and it still doesn't show the video.